# How to uniform a single UniformComponent?

Tags: opengl, haskell, shader

I want to set a one-GLfloat uniform value (so [`glUniform1f`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml) in the C API).
I'm looking through the documentation page for the Uniform module over [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Shaders-Uniform.html), and there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

I kind of expected an instance of `UniformComponent a => Uniform a`, but there isn't any.
It seems really obvious (especially since the functions of typeclass `UniformComponent` are hidden), so would it be bad practice? am I missing something? or is it truly overlooked and I have to use the raw bindings?

Answer (score 1):

For now I'm using the raw bindings.
So if it really is overlooked, it is possible to import just what you need from `Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.Raw` and you'll get the wrapped C API.
You can find the various uniform setters [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGLRaw-1.5.0.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-Raw-Core31.html#v:glUniform1f).

My usage looks like this:

```
UniformLocation tLoc <- get $ uniformLocation shaderProgram "t"
glUniform1f tLoc tValue
```

It's not the best solution, since, well, it's raw - you lose some abstraction (`UniformLocation`), and ad-hoc polymorphism (no typeclasses, so you use function name suffixes like you do in C).